# Computing $\langle0|T[Q(t_2)Q(t_1)]|0\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral

Given Hamiltonian $H=\frac{P^2}{2}+\frac{\omega^2}{2}Q^2$, compute $\langle0|T[Q(t_2)Q(t_1)]|0\rangle$, where $T$ is the time-ordering of the product, $|0\rangle$ is the ground state. Now set $\hbar=m=1$ and define
$$ Q(t)=e^{iHt}Qe^{-iHt} $$
and
$$Q|q\rangle=q|q\rangle $$

Apparently a hint to this question is that $H|n\rangle=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\omega |n\rangle$ and
$$Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(a+a^{\dagger})$$

Now I cannot see how to approach this question. The form $\langle0|T[Q(t_2)Q(t_1)]|0\rangle$ would suggest using the Feynman formula
$$\langle0|T[Q(t_2)Q(t_1)]|0\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int Dq \underline{q}(t_1)\underline{q}(t_2)e^{i\int_{\infty}^{\infty}dt L(\underline{q},\underline{\dot{q}})}$$
but this does correspond to the hint, nor can I see where to go with this.

What is the right approach to this question?

Comment: You should first figure out what is $Q(t)$ explicitly in terms of $a$ and $a^\dagger$, using Heisenberg's equation of motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the easy way to do this is to not use that formula -- which incidentally is part of a completely different formulation of quantum mechanics. The $q$s and $\dot{q}$s up inside the path integral are *classical* c-number valued paths, whose interference will give the quantum content in correlation functions. The problem you're being asked to solve seems to be aimed at teaching the *canonical* formalism, where observables are written in terms of creation and annihilation operators. The difference between the two perspectives is something that confused me quite a bit when I was first learning QFT.

You have everything you need to answer the question already. Perhaps it will be easier if you initially calculate $\langle 0 | T[Q(0)(Q(0)]|0\rangle$: then you'll see quite clearly that writing $Q$ in terms of creation and annihilation operators makes the matrix element easy to compute.

Then in order to do the general case you need to deal with the time ordered product, which means you'll have to break up the expression in two "cases" -- that's perfectly fine -- or you can use Heaviside step functions. No matter what you choose to do, you'll have a Hamiltonian in the exponential, but the action of the Hamiltonian on number eigenstates is simple, and you'll be able to find the answer by direct computation.

Comment: Sorry I am confused about the two perspectives. Could you elaborate on this? I am was unaware that there was two perspectives.

Comment: Just to be clear, this difference is mostly important for quantum field theory, which is what I assume you're learning. In quantum mechanics the path integral is less useful for computations so a practical minded quantum mechanicist will never have to worry about it.

Comment: The gist of it is: the path integral samples "classical" trajectories, in the sense that they have well defined $x$ and $\dot{x}$ at all times. I put quotation marks because of course the trajectories do not obey classical equations of motion. Indeed, they may even sample "impossible" paths such as those for which $\dot{x}$ exceeds unity. That is okay, because such paths always interfere destructively.

Comment: The quantum mechanical content of the theory is obtained by computing correlation functions according to the path integral formulae. It is the weighing of different paths by different phases that ensures that the formalism gives the correct answer. To reiterate, nothing inside the path integral is an "operator". $x$ and $\dot{x}$ are just c-number valued functions that are being integrated over.

Comment: The canonical formalism, in contrast, treats $x$ and $p$ as operators throughout. If you want to compute a correlation function, you have to express the operators in terms of creation and annihilation operators and see their action on the vacuum state. This is, in a sense the """"true"""" framework of quantum field theory, because it is in this formulation that the nature of the Hilbert space is manifest. What we mean by "a particle" is nothing but an eigenstate of the number operator, for instance.

Comment: So that's why you have expressions such as the last formula in your OP: it recognizes $Q$ as an operator and introduces the path integral as a handy calculational tool for correlation functions (the propagator, in this case). It can be confusing to people to understand that the $Q$s on the left side are operators and the $q$s and $\dot{q}$s on the right side are c-numbers, and not very many books actually state this outright. I was confused by it, and it seems you were too.